# I/O error during system call, Broken pipe

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I know this question was raised a lot, but i didn't find any solution.
I'm trying to upload big file using https but i'm getting exception " I/O error during system call, Broken pipe" same code works when i'm uploading it using http.

I read that this problem was discovered on Android 2.3, I'm using Android 4.3 and it still happens...

it also happens when I'm uploading small file.
it doesn't happen with small file if i remove con.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024); and uploading the file in one chunk (which i can't do with large files).

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this issue in S3 upload (Large file)

Just go to S3 bucket-> Choose Bucket-> Permissions -> Change Block All Public Access to -> OFF (According to your need)

If it still does not work, just try changing S3 Bucket Region